# Inner Join Query Advice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, inner-join

i need help on creating an inner join query.

I have 2 tables, blogs and followers.

In the blogs table i have all the blog information, and then in the followers i have two fields which are the user id and then the blog id that the user follows.

I want to create a query that will order the blogs by how many followers there are.

So this is an example of what i use to show what builds a user is following (for reference):

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogs INNER JOIN followers ON (blogs.id = followers.blogid) WHERE followers.userid='" .$usernamesesh. "'";
```

How can i go about creating a similiar query that will select all the blogs, but order them by highest to lowest followers.

Hope this makes sense, i cant get my head around this one for some reason!

The only other option is to add a number of followers field in the blogs table but that would involve changing my follow script etc.

Craig.

Comment: GROUP BY userid ORDER BY COUNT(userid) DESC something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact structure of you tables it's hard to tell. Assuming your followers table looks something like this

```
   blogid | userid
   -------+----------
     1    |  2
   -------+----------
     1    |  1
   -------+----------
     1    |  3
   -------+----------
     2    |  2
   -------+---------

 SELECT blogid, COUNT(userid) AS UserCount FROM followers 
 GROUP BY blogid ORDER BY UserCount DESC;
```

You can then to join the blogs table to get what ever columns you need from that table.

```
SELECT blogs.*, IFNULL(f.UserCount,0) AS UserCount
FROM blogs 
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blogid, COUNT(userid) AS UserCount FROM followers 
    GROUP BY blogid
 ) f
 ON f.blogid = blogs.id
 ORDER BY UserCount DESC
```

Comment: This is the one, almost there just need to add a where claus into it. I have a 'frontpage' field in my blogs table, where can i put the WHERE frontpage = 1 into the above query? I have tried in the usual places but getting errors,

Comment: before the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Hero, thanks for the help. Will take me a while to get my head around this query but i'll get there :)

Answer (score 0):

You could join against a subquery:

```
SELECT blogs.*, s.cnt
FROM blogs 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT blogid, count(*) as cnt 
                FROM followers
                GROUP BY blogid) s
     ON s.blogid = blogs.id
ORDER BY s.cnt
```

**Edit**

With

```
CREATE TABLE blogs (id);
create TABLE followers(blogid);
INSERT into blogs values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT into followers values (1),(1),(3);
```

You get:

```
id          cnt
----------  ----------
2
3           1
1           2
```

Comment: You can add an IFNULL, as suggested by @Mithrandir, to get 0 instead of null for blogs without followers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tweaking Mihai's suggestion a little bit, so add this string to the end of your query: `GROUP BY blogs.id ORDER BY COUNT(userid) DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT blogs.id, count(*) AS total FROM blogs INNER JOIN followers ON (blogs.id = followers.blogid) WHERE followers.userid='" .$usernamesesh. "'" GROUP BY blogs.id ORDER BY total;
```

Hope this helps